# Pass array values in PHP using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have this ajax function which inserts data using modal but I'm currently having a problem in passing the array values in my insert query. How can i convert the it to pass multiple information to my query ?

My input textbox in html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="author_lname[]" name="author_lname[]" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="First Name" id="author_fname[]" name="author_fname[]" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="author_mname[]" name="author_mname[]" placeholder="Middle Name / Initial" required>
```

Ajax function

```
     var getauthor_lname = $("#author_lname").val();
     var getauthor_fname = $("#author_fname").val();
     var getauthor_mname = $("#author_mname").val();
     var whatprocess = "ADDBOOK";
 $.ajax({
        url: "adminfunctions.php",
        method: "POST",
       data: {getauthor_lname:getauthor_lname, 
              getauthor_fname:getauthor_fname,
              getauthor_mname:getauthor_mname , 
              whatprocess : whatprocess
        },
        success: function(data) {
               var getdata = data.trim();
               if (getdata == "SUCCESS") {
                swal({
                      title: 'Success!',
                      text: '',
                      type: 'success',
                      confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success",
                      buttonsStyling: false
                    }).then(function() {
                      $("#datatables").load(window.location + " #datatables");
                                  });
                                }
                                else {
                                    swal({
                                        title: 'Sorry for the inconvenience!',
                                        text: "There's a problem. Please contact the technical support for any concerns and questions.!",
                                        type: 'error',
                                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
                                        buttonsStyling: false
                                    }).catch(swal.noop)
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                                console.log(jqXHR);
                            }
                        });
```

PHP FOR INSERTING AUTHORS

```
$getauthor_lname = $_POST["getauthor_lname"];
$getauthor_fname = $_POST["getauthor_fname"];
$getauthor_mname = $_POST["getauthor_mname"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($getauthor_fname); $i++) {
        if ($getauthor_fname[$i] != "" && $getauthor_mname[$i] != "" && $getauthor_lname[$i] != "") {
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_author (book_isbn, author_firstname, author_middlename, author_lastname) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?)";
            $stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
            $getauthor_lname[$i] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getauthor_lname[$i]));
            $getauthor_fname[$i] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getauthor_fname[$i]));
            $getauthor_mname[$i] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getauthor_mname[$i]));
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $getbook_isbn, $getauthor_fname[$i], $getauthor_mname[$i], $getauthor_lname[$i]);
            $stmt->execute();
        }else{

            echo "ERRORauthor";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$("#author_lname")` does not match the id of `author_lname[]`.  You have to match the id exactly.  Try `$("#author_lname\\[\\]")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would package all of my variables into an array and ship it from the AJAX call using data and unwrap the array at the PHP layer where i can the directly pass the values into the INSERT statement and just execute the query. I would think you validated your data already at the javascript layer to avoid data corruption. Hope this helps or reply if you have some more questions.

Quick question though: why do you have your id and name set to be arrays. I wouldn't think those are necessary for a single input field

```
var author_lname = $('#author_lname').val()
var author_fname = $('#author_fname').val()
var author_mname = $('#author_mname').val()
var whatprocess = 'ADDBOOK'

var entries = {'author_lname': author_lname, 'author_mname': author_mname, 'author_fname': author_fname, 'whatprocess': whatprocess}
var json = JSON.stringify(entries)

$.ajax({
  url: 'functioncall.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: { entry: entries },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    // var getdata = data.trim();
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    console.log(jqXHR)
  }
})
```

```
$author_fname   =   $author_info['author_fname'];
$author_mname   =   $author_info['author_mname'];
$author_lname   =   $author_info['author_lname'];

if ( !(empty($author_fname)) && !(empty($author_mname)) && !(empty($author_lname)) ) {
    $query      =   "INSERT INTO tbl_author (book_isbn, author_firstname, author_middlename, author_lastname) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?)";
    $stmt       =   $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $getbook_isbn, $getauthor_fname[$i], $getauthor_mname[$i], htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($author_lname)));
    $stmt->execute();
}
else{
    echo "ERRORauthor";
}
```

Comment: Im kinda new to ajax and php , would you mind showing how can it  be done ?